# Docker swarm php-fpm container keeps restarting

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, fpm

I created a basic LAPP stack which runs flawlessly on localhost with `docker-compose`. When I try to make it run with Swarm on production server (1 manager only, no workers), all services go up and get replicated (1/1) but the php-fpm one which keeps restarting with **no apparent error**.

`docker service ls`

```
ID             NAME                    MODE         REPLICAS   IMAGE                  PORTS
p0rdrdfmso6x   traefik_reverse-proxy   replicated   1/1        traefik:v2.4           *:80->80/tcp, *:443->443/tcp
e6vwlo9iw2ny   my_stack_apache         replicated   1/1        apache:latest          *:8000->80/tcp
qy5yigbcjryr   my_stack_ftp            replicated   1/1        fauria/vsftpd:latest   *:20-21->20-21/tcp, *:22100-22110->22100-22110/tcp
n5f9v6bd2854   my_stack_php            replicated   0/1        php:latest
rcnbq4vnoz1j   my_stack_postgres       replicated   1/1        postgres:9.5.24
```

If we focus on `php-fpm` container :

`docker service ps my_stack_php`

```
ID             NAME                  IMAGE        NODE                        DESIRED STATE   CURRENT STATE             ERROR     PORTS
j6mp3ka40cyo   my_stack_php.1        php:latest   node.address                Ready           Ready 2 seconds ago
ezztpsjoglwy    \_ my_stack_php.1    php:latest   node.address                Shutdown        Complete 3 seconds ago
gnqjhwpi5y72    \_ my_stack_php.1    php:latest   node.address                Shutdown        Complete 9 seconds ago
0agr3tw0bb9g    \_ my_stack_php.1    php:latest   node.address                Shutdown        Complete 15 seconds ago
9a6wsdp4tqqn    \_ my_stack_php.1    php:latest   node.address                Shutdown        Complete 21 seconds ago
```

If I look to the logs :
`docker service logs my_stack_php`

```
my_stack_php.1.igd8x7a6ysdi@node.address    | Interactive shell
my_stack_php.1.57td5iuk1wwy@node.address    | Interactive shell
my_stack_php.1.r03jn931l1uf@node.address    | Interactive shell
my_stack_php.1.igd8x7a6ysdi@node.address    |
my_stack_php.1.r03jn931l1uf@node.address    |
my_stack_php.1.1huf2pdd0bq0@node.address    | Interactive shell
my_stack_php.1.57td5iuk1wwy@node.address    |
my_stack_php.1.1huf2pdd0bq0@node.address    |
```

It behaves like a container running a command which would end with succes in a few seconds. Swarm launches then an new container to keep the restart contract. However, my php-fpm Dockerfile provide the `-F` argument that should keep the process running :

PHP Dockerfile

```
FROM centos:7.4

# ... all installs from Centos to add PHP 7.2 from Remi Collet repositories

RUN mkdir -p /run/php-fpm
RUN usermod -a -G ftp apache

WORKDIR /var/www/html

EXPOSE 9000

# Run in foreground as root (in container POV)
CMD ["php-fpm", "-R", "-F"]
```

`docker-compose.yaml`

```yaml
version: '3.9'
services:
  postgres:
    image: "postgres:9.5.24"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: /run/secret/postgres_db
      POSTGRES_USER: /run/secret/postgres_user
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: /run/secret/postgres_password
    volumes:
      - database:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    secrets:
      - postgres_db
      - postgres_user
      - postgres_password
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '0.15'
          memory: 128m
    networks:
      - internal

  apache:
    env_file: .env
    image: apache:latest
    build:
      context: ./docker/images/apache2.4
      dockerfile: prod.Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8000:80
    environment:
      FPM_HOST: php:9000
    volumes:
      - ./docker/logs/apache/:/var/log/httpd/

    networks:
      - traefik-public
      - internal

    deploy:
      labels:
        - "traefik.enable=true"
        - "traefik.http.routers.my_stack.rule=Host(`my-host.com`)"
        - "traefik.http.routers.my_stack.entrypoints=websecure"
        - "traefik.http.routers.my_stack.tls.certresolver=letsencryptresolver"
        - "traefik.http.services.my_stack.loadbalancer.server.port=80"
        - "traefik.port=80"

      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '0.15'
          memory: 128m
 php:
    env_file: .env
    image: php:latest
#    links:
#      - ftp
#      - apache
    build:
      context: ./docker/images/php
      dockerfile: prod.Dockerfile
#      args:
#        TIMEZONE: 'Europe/Paris'
    volumes:
      - ftp_data:/var/www/ftp:rw


    networks:
      - internal

    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '0.20'
          memory: 512m

  ftp:
    env_file: .env
    image: "fauria/vsftpd:latest"
    ports:
      - "20:20"
      - "21:21"
      - "22100-22110:22100-22110"
    environment:
      FTP_USER: apache
      FTP_PASS: /run/secret/automation_client_password
      PASV_ADDRESS: 127.0.0.1
      PASV_MIN_PORT: 22100
      PASV_MAX_PORT: 22110
    volumes:
      - ftp_data:/home/vsftpd/apache:rw

    networks:
      - traefik-public
      - internal

    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '0.15'
          memory: 128m
volumes:
  ftp_data:
  database:

secrets:
  postgres_db:
    external: true
  postgres_user:
    external: true
  postgres_password:
    external: true
  automation_client_password:
    external: true

networks:
  traefik-public:
    external: true
  internal:
    external: false
```

Anyone got a clue about this? Any helps/tips will be appreciated.

Comment: Its logging "Interactive Shell" as though you have nothing in the container for it to actually execute. So its waiting for input. But as swarm containers dont get an attached tty that fails and it falls out.
Perhaps add a "entrypoint.sh" script to the php container with a bit of logging in it so you can get a bit of diagnostics out of the container other than that one log message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't like this kind of answer, but replica's all went live after complete reboot.